# Finding a path in 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mapping, search-path

I have MySQL database with no constraints definition and I also have a multidimensional array in PHP which contains information about tables relations in this database. The array is in this format (only an example):

```
array(20){
    ps_attribute_lang => array(2) {
      id_attribute => array(2) {
         totable => "ps_attribute" (12)
         tocolumn => "id_attribute" (12)
      }
      id_lang => array(2) {
         totable => "ps_lang" (7)
         tocolumn => "id_lang" (7)
      }
    }
    ps_cart => array(4) {
      id_lang => array(2) {
         totable => "ps_lang" (7)
         tocolumn => "id_lang" (7)
      }
      id_address_delivery => array(2) {
         totable => "ps_address" (10)
         tocolumn => "id_address" (10)
      }
      id_address_invoice => array(2) {
         totable => "ps_address" (10)
         tocolumn => "id_address" (10)
      }
      id_customer => array(2) {
         totable => "ps_customer" (11)
         tocolumn => "id_customer" (11)
      }
    }
    ps_cart_product => array(1) {
      id_product => array(2) {
         totable => "ps_product" (10)
         tocolumn => "id_product" (10)
      }
    }
 ...
}
```

Now I'm wondering how can one find a path in this database from one table to another.

Let me give an example. Let's say we have following tables in our database:

- states(id_state, name)
- cities(id_city, id_state, name)
- streets(id_street, id_city, name)
- houses(id_house, id_street, color, number)
- people(id_house, name)

Now let's say that each time I want to find house with some properties (e.g. every blue house that resides in Chicago). For this I need to generate SQL command.¨

SELECT part of SQL is simple (e.g. `SELECT houses.id`). WHERE part of SQL is also very simple (e.g. `WHERE cities.name = 'Chicago' AND house.color = 'blue'`). **The problem is in "connecting" tables in JOIN part of SQL**.

I simply need to search this multidimensional relations array and find a path that connects all tables that contain conditions from WHERE part of SQL AND SELECT part of SQL.

In this case I want to get this:

```
SELECT house.id
FROM house
JOIN street ON(house.id_street = street.id)
JOIN city ON(street.id_city = city.id)
WHERE house.color = 'blue' AND city.name = 'chicago'
```

Do you know any algorithm that is capable of getting this kind of info from this structure?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have those 5 tables which are inherently related because of the columns contained in each field. For example, cities has id_state which relates to the states table. There is only 4 relations (cities->states, streets->cities, houses->streets, people->houses). What are you expecting this algorithm to provide you?

Comment: Computer doesn't know that these tables are related, because there is no information about relations in DB. However these information are in PHP array, which I manually created. Now I want this algorithm to take this array, go through it and tell me, that I need to JOIN tables house, street and city for SQL command to work properly.

Comment: Now that I think about it I will probably break this array down to oriented graph of PHP objects and apply some graph search algorithm to get what I need.